# adding C# objects to a VB web project in Visual Studio 2012. Getting C# templates?

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, visual-studio-2012, global-asax

I'm not sure how I was able to do this before in VS 2005, but I recently migrated a VS2005 VB web site to a VS 2012 Web Solution/Project.  The solutoin already has both VB and C# Classes in seperate folders and is working. I now want to add a global.asax, but in C#. When I attempt add new item I can't seem to get to C# templates from Visual Studio.

And thinking forward, will I be able to slowly turn my VB solution into an all C# solution Page by Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freely mix match VB and C# in a `Web Site`, not in a `Web Application`. So if you want to continue with that freedom, you'll have to stick with Web Site Projects.

IMHO the decision to migrate from VB to C# can be done either way - slowly in web sites by mixing, and/or really going for it and "forcing" yourself to do C# only in an `Application Project`.

Hth...